# Redirecting localhost/xxx to localhost/xxx.php in WAMP

Tags: php, .htaccess, wamp, wampserver

In Ubuntu/Mac, going to, say, localhost/page automatically redirects to localhost/page.php.

But this doesn't work in Windows. How do you make stuff like localhost/asdf redirect to localhost/asdf.php?

Comment: Not enough details... but most likely you need to add `Options +MultiViews` : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am assuming that you know what an .htaccess file is.

You can achieve this by two methods:

**Method 1:**

```
`#1- Loads the page asdf.php but 
     displays asdf in the address bar  

RewriteBase   /site  
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)?$ $1.php `
```

**Method 2:**

```
`#2- Loads the page asdf.php and 
displays asdf.php in the address bar. 
The R flag tells Apache to redirect to the
url. 

RewriteBase   /site  
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)?$ $1.php [R]`
```

I hope this will help you.