# htaccess to rewrite url

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I heard you can use htaccess to rewrite the website url. For example I have a php page to view threads/posts which looks like this:

`http://website.com/view.php?id=133`

I have been told I could make it look like

`http://website.com/view/133`

I also have this link

`http://website.com/delete.php?id=144`

and I want it to look like this

`http://website.com/delete/144`

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: You read the manual and than you do what you want: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ - The functionality you look for is in the rewrite module: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html for starters there is the [introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ([a-z])/([0-9])\ $1.php?id=$2
```

([a-z]) will replace your page name  ([0-9]) will replace your id respectively in right hand side

Please refer

http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php

Comment: but then you wont be able to use relative paths inside your html page. for eg : `css/style.css` in your `http://website.com/view/133` would be `view/css/style.css`. You will have to use absolute file paths for your css, js, img files, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do all that using .htaccess.

Check out my answer [Redirecting localhost/xxx to localhost/xxx.php in WAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6868535/redirecting-localhost-xxx-to-localhost-xxx-php-in-wamp/6876759#6876759)

I hope it helps.

Comment: check if the mod_rewrite  module is installed and enabled in your apache installation?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([0-9]+)$ $1.php?id=$2 [NC,L]
```

You have to give the url as  http://website.com/delete/144, then it will be redirected to delete.php with 144 as id.

For example,

```
<a href="http://website.com/delete/$id">Delete</a>
```

Comment: and put this in a file named .htaccess in your website's root folder. Also include the line `RewriteEngine On` before the RewriteRule line.